# How to build the following tables?

Tags: python, pandas

Hello I have process a excel file and to take some parameters of it to create many tables the structure of the tables is the following:

```
"AWK|USL|R|SVKDIKG_tVstiKg|S|[PARAMETER1]~BURAGO~[PARAMETER2]~WVDG~333" "AFUSLR~USLSSHS~Farm~~%ERD_ARGV=MR4567.%VRSD%.%23WF%.333.%RVB%.tRt"
"AWK|USL|R|Bimbo|S|[PARAMETER3]~K~999" "USLo99941VRR.VxV"
"AWK|USL|R|Bimbo|S|[PARAMETER3]~Q~999" "USLo99941VRR.VxV"
"AWK|USL|R|Ford|S|[PARAMETER3]~K~999" "[PARAMETER3]~K"
"AWK|USL|R|Ford|S|[PARAMETER3]~Q~999" "[PARAMETER3]~K"
```

The parameters that I need to use to create the tables are contained in a excel file and they looks as follows:

```
123123,RIBICOM,FACTIBLE
050944,TELCOM,423423
.
.
.
42342,CORPS,233243
```

The idea is to take the "," as a column separator, where the fist column would be the "PARAMETER1", second column "PARAMETER2" and finally "PARAMETER3" the third column raw by raw, for every raw or this archive I need to produce one table filling the place holders of my template as follows:

```
"AWK|USL|R|SVKDIKG_tVstiKg|S|123123~BURAGO~RIBICOM~WVDG~333" "AFUSLR~USLSSHS~Farm~~%ERD_ARGV=MR4567.%VRSD%.%23WF%.333.%RVB%.tRt"
"AWK|USL|R|Bimbo|S|FACTIBLE~K~999" "USLo99941VRR.VxV"
"AWK|USL|R|Bimbo|S|FACTIBLE~Q~999" "USLo99941VRR.VxV"
"AWK|USL|R|Ford|S|FACTIBLE~K~999" "FACTIBLE~K"
"AWK|USL|R|Ford|S|FACTIBLE~Q~999" "FACTIBLE~K"
```

to be more clear the place holders of the template are the followings:

```
[PARAMETER1]
[PARAMETER2]
[PARAMETER3]
```

those are the things that I need to fill,

The example of above would be the desired output for the first row, I need to produce a txt file with all the tables concatenated, in order to achieve this I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
xl = pd.ExcelFile("Book1.xlsx")
#to clean from duplicates
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df=df.drop_duplicates()
#these are the values that I am concatenating below
Parameter1=df[u'Header1 ']
Parameter2=df[u'Header2 ']
Parameter3=df[u'Header3 ']

#This is the dataframe with the corresponding columns
important_Parameters=df[u'Header1 '].astype(str)+","+df[u'Header2 '].astype(str)+","+df[u'Header3 '].astype(str)

#to write my dataframe on disk.
important_Parameters.to_csv("important33.txt", index=False)
```

I am not sure of what would be the best approach to proceed  since I used to do that kind of things in bash using "sed" and "awk" but this time I would like to try using pandas and python I really appreciate any suggestion to proceed with this specific task.

Comment: the input and output looks the same, can you clarify the same ? Also what are trying to do Parameter1, Parameter2 & Parameter3

Comment: yes sure In fact I just need to replace the things inside the following symbols "[", "]" I made some place holders named: [PARAMETER1], [PARAMETER2] and [PARAMETER3] stated in uppercases,

Comment: Do you have to use dataframes ? Can you use dictionaries or json instead ?

Comment: @WeShall, I don't need to use dataframes, I accept suggestions in  order to overcome this situation, thanks a lot for the support.

Comment: Try something like this... And if it looks on the right track, help me understand what your output should be and can help with the last part as well... import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile("Book1.xlsx")

df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df = df.drop_duplicates()

excel_input = df.values.tolist()

for index, record in enumerate(excel_input):
    PARAMETER1 = record.split(',', 2)[0]
    PARAMETER2 = record.split(',', 2)[1]
    PARAMETER3 = record.split(',', 2)[2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you try this

```
import pandas as pd
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
df = pd.read_csv("param.csv")
print df
df=df.drop_duplicates()
filename='sample.txt'

print "\n\nReplace with new values"
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print "New Values \n\n"
    print row 
    f=open(filename)
    filedata = f.read()
    filedata=filedata.replace("[PARAMETER1]",row[0])
    filedata=filedata.replace('[PARAMETER2]',row[1])
    filedata=filedata.replace('[PARAMETER3]',row[2])
    print filedata
```

output

```
      Parameter1 Parameter2 Parameter3
    0    123123A    RIBICOM   FACTIBLE
    1   050944BS     TELCOM     423423


    Replace with new values
    New Values


    Parameter1     123123A
    Parameter2     RIBICOM
    Parameter3    FACTIBLE
    Name: 0, dtype: object
    AWK|USL|R|SVKDIKG_tVstiKg|S|123123A~BURAGO~RIBICOM~WVDG~333 AFUSLR~USLSSHS~Farm~
    ~%ERD_ARGV=MR4567.%VRSD%.%23WF%.333.%RVB%.tRt
    AWK|USL|R|Bimbo|S|FACTIBLE~K~999 USLo99941VRR.VxV
    AWK|USL|R|Bimbo|S|FACTIBLE~Q~999 USLo99941VRR.VxV
    AWK|USL|R|Ford|S|FACTIBLE~K~999 FACTIBLE~K
    AWK|USL|R|Ford|S|FACTIBLE~Q~999 FACTIBLE~K
    New Values


    Parameter1    050944BS
    Parameter2      TELCOM
    Parameter3      423423
    Name: 1, dtype: object
    AWK|USL|R|SVKDIKG_tVstiKg|S|050944BS~BURAGO~TELCOM~WVDG~333 AFUSLR~USLSSHS~Farm~
    ~%ERD_ARGV=MR4567.%VRSD%.%23WF%.333.%RVB%.tRt
    AWK|USL|R|Bimbo|S|423423~K~999 USLo99941VRR.VxV
    AWK|USL|R|Bimbo|S|423423~Q~999 USLo99941VRR.VxV
    AWK|USL|R|Ford|S|423423~K~999 423423~K
    AWK|USL|R|Ford|S|423423~Q~999 423423~K
```

Sample.txt

```
"AWK|USL|R|SVKDIKG_tVstiKg|S|[PARAMETER1]~BURAGO~[PARAMETER2]~WVDG~333" "AFUSLR~USLSSHS~Farm~~%ERD_ARGV=MR4567.%VRSD%.%23WF%.333.%RVB%.tRt"
"AWK|USL|R|Bimbo|S|[PARAMETER3]~K~999" "USLo99941VRR.VxV"
"AWK|USL|R|Bimbo|S|[PARAMETER3]~Q~999" "USLo99941VRR.VxV"
"AWK|USL|R|Ford|S|[PARAMETER3]~K~999" "[PARAMETER3]~K"
"AWK|USL|R|Ford|S|[PARAMETER3]~Q~999" "[PARAMETER3]~K"
```

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for the support this was very helpful just one thing what would be the content of the file called: sample.txt, following your approach.

Comment: Where is the file that contains the tables?

Comment: I just included the content from Sample.txt

Comment: I understand, it is now clear for me, thanks a lot for the support, this was very useful.